# What is a CssHierarchyControl?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, controls

There are [0 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CssHierarchyControl) on SO for `CssHierarchyControl` and [3 irrelevant results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=CssHierarchyControl%20C%23) on Google for `CssHierarchyControl C#`.

What is this control? How does it differ from a `ComboBox`?

From the tooltips from hovering on each of the controls: `ComboBox` is at v4.5.0.0, whereas `CssHierarchyControl` states v11.0.0.0.

[image: CHC]

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing. Perhaps you got it from a third-party library. and what makes you compare it to the version of ComboBox? Built-in controls only *tend* to have the same versions as each other because they are developed in parallel to the frameworks in which they are released; but that is *not* a hard-and-fast rule - and does not apply *at all* to third-party controls.

Comment: @AndrewBarber This is from a default installation of VS Ultimate 2012. It behaves exactly like a ComboBox when dragged onto a form. I do see from the icon though that it looks like a custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CssHierachyControl` is on my machine as well.  Looking under the "Choose Items" context menu on the toolbox I see it listed as part of the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` namespace in the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` assembly.  It is version 11.0.0.0 as well, which matches the version number of Visual Studio 2012, which is 11.

Looking at the class in dotPeek it does inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` so it is a combo box.

It is not listed as part of the [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.aspx) namespace so it is not meant for public consumption so you should remove it from your tools list since there is no reason to ever use it.

Comment: Good answer! Do you have any idea why it's in the toolbox in the first place?

Comment: @DannyBeckett - sorry no idea - it wasn't added to mine.  It could have been accidentally added using the "Choose Items" dialog or perhaps come install application had a bug.